# While ends even if the condition is unfilled Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I have 4 people around table and between each of them is one tool. They are 4 separated threads and their run method tells them to pick tool on the right and left and eat, then put both tools back to the table so others can eat too and do it all again.

[image]

Here is the while loop that forces each of them to pick the tools. It is in their class and i call it from run method.

```
public void sbirejHulky() throws InterruptedException
    {
        while((left != true) && (right != true))
        {
            right = rightTool.getTool(this); // try to grab right tool
            aktualizuj(); // This actualise the graphic
            Thread.sleep(Filozofove.getRandom());
            left = leftTool.getTool(this); // try to grab left tool
            Thread.sleep(Filozofove.getRandom());
            aktualizuj();
            System.out.println("this.right +" "+this.left);
        }
    }
```

This while should run as long, as left and right both are false right ? But sometimes it ends when left is true but right is still false and I dont understand how is it possible.

Method getTool is synchronized and returns true if the tool the grab was succesful and returns false if someone has it at this moment.

I will be glad for any help

---

Edit

```
public synchronized boolean getTool(Filozof filozof) throws InterruptedException 
    {
    if (owner != null)
            {
             if(filozof.isRight())
                    {
                        filozof.setRight(filozof.getRightTool().putToolBack());
                    }
             if(filozof.isLeft())
                    {
                        filozof.setLeft(filozof.getLeftTool().putToolBack());
                    }
                    return false;
           }
           else
           {
            owner = filozof; 
            return true;
           }
   }
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile!!!

Comment: *"But sometimes it ends when left is true but right is still false..."* Right. `&&` means "AND". Which means the loop only continues while **both** conditions are true ("while A and B...").

Comment: Side note: Using `var == true` (or `false`) or `var != true` (or `false`) with booleans is poor practice; you **already** have a boolean value. Just use the variable itself (`var`) rather than `var == true` or `var != false`, and use `!var` instead of `var != true` or `var == false`.

Comment: Andreas - I can upload this whole little project somewhere if you want too... i just picked the sample that doesnt work right.

Comment: @MirekMareš: "doesn't work right" and "doesn't compile" are very different things.

Comment: How would uploading whole project be any help, when the code **cannot** compile. It's not failing to compile because we're lacking the field declarations. It's failing to compile because the **syntax** is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas - Maybe i miss something here, but i can run the program without any compile errors.

Comment: €@MirekMareš: Look closely at the `System.out.println("this.right +" "+this.left);` line.

Comment: If `rightTool.getTool()` is truly "try to grab right tool", as the comment says, then it might fail to grab the tool, right? If you can't grab the *right* tool, why do you still try to grab the *left* tool. What happens if all 4 successfully grab the *right* tool? Then none of them can grab the *left* tool, and they will all sit there and stare at each other, and nothing will happen.

Comment: I will edit the post with the grab method... but they dont stare all at each other, because when they cant grab it, they put anything they have to the table.... and then they sleep for random time before they try again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is wrong with that ? it writes into console what is current state of right and left hand or do i miss something ?

Comment: @MirekMareš *"when they cant grab it, they put anything they have to the table"* Really? Where in the code does that happen?

Comment: @MirekMareš *"do i miss something ?"* Yes. **Look** at the code. There are 3(!) quotes. They are unbalanced!!!

Comment: I have a *philosophical* question. Is the tool between them a *fork*?

Comment: @Kayaman It's a [Knork](https://www.google.com/search?q=Knork): A Knife + Fork.

Comment: @Kayaman yes... fork and knife

Comment: @Andreas I just edited the post with the grabTool method. It checks if the tool has owner at the moment, if yes then it tells the one who wanted it to put all what he has to the table by the putToolBack method and returns false... if there is not owner then he grabs the tool and method returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition means that the loop should continue while both right and left are false, and it stops once any of them is true. You should try with `while((left != true) || (right != true))`, meaning the loop will stop only once both are true.

Comment: Why? What did you change? *Why* did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers. *(not my dv)*

Comment: This works, the problem was in the condition and you are right... Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this statement true or false, "two plus two is five AND I am not bald". Regardless of how much or little hair I have on my head, this statement is false. It's only true if both sides of the AND are satisfied, and only one is.

```
    (left != true) && (right != true)
```

Similarly, this is false if `left != true` is false, regardless of the value of `right`.

```
    while((left != true) && (right != true))
```

This continues the loop only while the condition is true, and the condition is not true if `left != true` is false. So it will stop if `left` is `true`, regardless of the value of `right`.

In the future, don't do things like `left != true`. Since `left` is already a boolean that is either true or false, you don't need to compare it to make it a boolean. If you want to invert it, use `!left`.

A simpler, and correct, way to do this would be:

```
while (! (left && right))
```

You're done when `left && right` is true. So you want to keep looping while that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion works too :) the problem was really in the condition itself.